# PHP-FPM в какую папку положить файлы?

Tags: php, php-fpm

Сразу оговорюсь, что в php и связаной с ним инфраструктуре я полный ноль.

Так вот. Мне нужно исполнить php файл на локальной машине. Обратиться нужно именно по сети, а не запустить интерпретатор в консоли, т.к. результат работы скрипта зависит от параметров урла. Ничего проксировать/балансировать мне не нужно. Доверие к скрипту абсолютное.

Я сделал

```
sudo apt install php
```

потом сразу удалил установившиеся с ним apache и apache2. Ну потому что.

Оказалось, что с ним еще установилось php-fpm.
Редактирую `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` и прописываю `listen = 127.0.0.1:8888`.

В какую папочку мне положить файлы и/или какую строчку в конфиге еще отредактировать, чтобы при вводе в адресную строку браузера `http://localhost:8888/???/myscript.php` я видел результат исполнения скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам php с версии 5.4.0 [имеет встроенный веб-сервер](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php). Он не предназначен для production, но для "потестировать" вполне пригоден.

Если кратко, то вам надо сложить ваш код в любую папку, зайти в эту папку и выполнить `php -S localhost:8000`, а затем зайти браузером на `http://localhost:8000/`.

Но я всё-таки посоветовал бы поднять его в связке с nginx, чтобы иметь представление как это всё работает на самом деле. Достаточно неплохая статья на эту тему [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/320036/).

Comment: спасибо большое! похоже это как раз то что мне нужно. что касается nginx, у меня есть опыт его настройки для проксирования node.js и отдачи статики, но в данном случае не хочу городить сложную систему на локальной машине чтобы просто запустить вспомогательный скриптец)

Comment: Для того, чтобы не мучать себя рутиной - есть ansible :)